# How to make a rectangle appear after another in pygame?

Tags: python, pygame

I've been learning python and just started to play with coding in Pygame. My current program is a game in which the character is a fly, who must avoid being killed by a fly swatter. The game must first randomly display a translucent yellow square anywhere on the screen. This square represents where the swatter will strike in 2 seconds, giving the player time to fly out of that strike area. When the swatter strikes, I want to blit an opaque square to the game in the exact location of the fainter square. This square will kill the player if they are within it when it appears. Although I plan on displaying messages and adding other things of this nature, the opaque square(or the swatter strike) should terminate the game session. I have already created both of the squares, but I need the opaque one to come after the translucent one, and in the same location. After each strike i'd like the squares to disappear and the process to repeat. if anyone has any insight as to how I could go about 1) blitting the translucent square in a random location and 2) having the darker square "strike" that same location in 2 seconds, and then disappear and repeat, I would be extremely grateful. I have tried using the time.sleep() function and it has not worked. 
Many thanks!!

(please excuse my somewhat messy code!)

```
import pygame, random, time, sys, math
from pygame.locals import *

pygame.init()

display_width = 800
display_height = 600

gameDisplay = pygame.display.set_mode((display_width,display_height))
pygame.display.set_caption('Fly Dodger')

black = (0,0,0)
white = (255,255,255)
yellow = (255,255,0)

fly_width = 70

clock = pygame.time.Clock()

crashed = False

flyImg = pygame.image.load("Fly.png")
flyImg = pygame.transform.scale(flyImg, (80, 80))

#THe faintswatter is the faint image/square I want to appear first. 
faintSwatter = pygame.image.load("faintswatter.png")
faintSwatter = pygame.transform.scale(faintSwatter, (400, 510))

#The realswatter is the square that appears after the fainter one, in the same position. 
realswatter = pygame.image.load("swatter.png")
realswatter = pygame.transform.scale(realswatter, (400, 510))

windowImg = pygame.image.load("window.jpg")
windowImg = pygame.transform.scale(windowImg, (800,600))
pygame.display.update()

def fly(x,y):
    gameDisplay.blit(flyImg, (x,y))

def border():
    x_change = 0
    y_change = 0

def swatter_Function(swatterx, swattery, swaterw, swaterh, color):
    pygame.draw.rect(gameDisplay, color, [swatterx, swattery, swaterw, swaterh])

def things_dodged(count):
    font = pygame.font.SysFont(None, 25)
    text = font.render("Dodged: "+str(count), True, green)
    gameDisplay.blit(text, (0,0))

def message_display(text):
    largeText = pygame.font.Font("freesansbold.ttf",115)
    TextSurf, TextRect = text_objects(text, largeText)
    TextRect.center = ((display_width/2),(display_height/2))
    gameDisplay.blit(TextSurf, TextRect)

def gameloop():
    x = (display_width * .45)
    y = (display_height * .4)
    x_change = 0
    y_change = 0

    gameExit = False

    while not gameExit:
        for event in pygame.event.get():

            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                crashed = True

            if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:

                if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                    x_change = -5

                elif event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                    x_change = 5

                elif event.key == pygame.K_UP:
                    y_change = -5

                elif event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
                    y_change = 5


        x += x_change
        y += y_change


            if event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
                if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT or event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                    x_change = 0

            if event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
                if event.key == pygame.K_UP or event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
                    y_change = 0

        gameDisplay.blit(windowImg, (0,0))
        fly(x,y)
        gameDisplay.blit(faintSwatter,(1,1))
        gameDisplay.blit(realswatter, (2,2))
        pygame.display.update()

        if x > display_width - fly_width or x < 0:
            gameExit = True

        if y > display_height - fly_width or y < 0:
            gameExit = True



        pygame.display.update()
        clock.tick(60)
gameloop()
pygame.quit()
quit()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have made some major changes.. look for #changes.

These are the images I have used : https://i.stack.imgur.com/TrLyX.jpg

```
import pygame, random, time, sys, math
from pygame.locals import *

pygame.init()

display_width = 800
display_height = 600

gameDisplay = pygame.display.set_mode((display_width,display_height))
pygame.display.set_caption('Fly Dodger')

black = (0,0,0)
white = (255,255,255)
yellow = (255,255,0)

fly_width = 70

clock = pygame.time.Clock()

crashed = False

flyImg = pygame.image.load("Fly.png").convert() #changes
flyImg = pygame.transform.scale(flyImg, (80, 80))

#THe faintswatter is the faint image/square I want to appear first.
faintSwatter = pygame.image.load("faintswatter.png").convert() #changes
faintSwatter = pygame.transform.scale(faintSwatter, (400, 510))
faintSwatter.set_alpha(128) #changes


#The realswatter is the square that appears after the fainter one, in the same position.
realswatter = pygame.image.load("swatter.png").convert() #changes
realswatter = pygame.transform.scale(realswatter, (400, 510))

windowImg = pygame.image.load("window.jpg")
windowImg = pygame.transform.scale(windowImg, (800,600))
pygame.display.update()

def fly(x,y):
    gameDisplay.blit(flyImg, (x,y))

def border():
    x_change = 0
    y_change = 0

def swatter_Function(swatterx, swattery, swaterw, swaterh, color):
    pygame.draw.rect(gameDisplay, color, [swatterx, swattery, swaterw, swaterh])

def things_dodged(count):
    font = pygame.font.SysFont(None, 25)
    text = font.render("Dodged: "+str(count), True, green)
    gameDisplay.blit(text, (0,0))

def message_display(text):
    largeText = pygame.font.Font("freesansbold.ttf",115)
    TextSurf, TextRect = text_objects(text, largeText)
    TextRect.center = ((display_width/2),(display_height/2))
    gameDisplay.blit(TextSurf, TextRect)

def gameloop():
    x = (display_width * .45)
    y = (display_height * .4)
    x_change = 0
    y_change = 0

    #changes
    totalPlaytime = 0.0
    faintDisplay = True
    solidDisplay = False
    choosenCoords = False

    gameExit = False

    while not gameExit:
        for event in pygame.event.get():

            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                #changes
                gameExit = True

            if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:

                if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                    x_change = -5

                elif event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                    x_change = 5

                elif event.key == pygame.K_UP:
                    y_change = -5

                elif event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
                    y_change = 5

            #changes - moved in the loop
            if event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
                if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT or event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                    x_change = 0

            if event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
                if event.key == pygame.K_UP or event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
                    y_change = 0

        #changes - moved out of the loop at the end
        x += x_change
        y += y_change

        gameDisplay.blit(windowImg, (0,0))
        fly(x,y)

        #changes
        if faintDisplay and not choosenCoords:
            xSwatter = random.randrange(0,display_width-400)
            ySwatter = random.randrange(0,display_height-510)
            choosenCoords = True
            faintSwatterBeginTime = totalPlaytime

        if faintDisplay:
            if totalPlaytime - faintSwatterBeginTime < 2.0:
                gameDisplay.blit(faintSwatter,(xSwatter,ySwatter))
            else:
                faintDisplay = False
                solidDisplay = True
                solidSwatterBeginTime = totalPlaytime

        if solidDisplay:
            if totalPlaytime - solidSwatterBeginTime < 0.5:
                gameDisplay.blit(realswatter, (xSwatter,ySwatter))
                if ((x+80 > xSwatter) and (x < xSwatter+400) and (y+80 > ySwatter) and (y < ySwatter+510)):
                    crashed = True
                    gameExit = True
            else:
                solidDisplay = False
                faintDisplay = True
                choosenCoords = False
        #changes end

        pygame.display.update()

        if x > display_width - fly_width or x < 0:
            gameExit = True

        if y > display_height - fly_width or y < 0:
            gameExit = True

        #pygame.display.update()

        #changes
        milliseconds = clock.tick(60)
        totalPlaytime += milliseconds/1000.0


gameloop()
pygame.quit()
quit()
```

I am a beginner too.. so excuse me for such verbose code. The changes I have made are: Added time calculation, Made the flatter transparent up to some degree, Added collision functionality (you can also use colliderect), Added the algorithm for letting the faint swatter stay for 2 seconds and the solid one for 0.5 seconds.

Comment: Thank you so much! It works great and this is a great way to accomplish the goal of this game. Great work especially if you're a beginner!

Answer (score 1):

I'd use a `timer` variable and subtract the `dt` (delta time - the time since the last `clock.tick` call) from it to get a countdown. In the example below I use a variable for the currently selected image (`swatterImg`). This `swatterImg` is set to the faint one first, then if the timer is between 0s and 1.5s I set it to the `realswatter` image and do the collision detection, if the timer is below 0s I reset the timer and the image and generate a new position for the swatter. The `fly` and `swatter` are `pygame.Rect`s which store the positions and are also used for the collision detection. In the drawing phase, you can just blit the fly image and the current swatter image at their respective rects. (I've removed the code that quits the game automatically, since it's not necessary for the example and annoying for the user.)

```
import sys
import random
import pygame as pg


pg.init()

displayrect = pg.Rect(0, 0, 800, 600)
gameDisplay = pg.display.set_mode(displayrect.size)
pg.display.set_caption('Fly Dodger')
clock = pg.time.Clock()

flyImg = pg.Surface((80, 80))
flyImg.fill((220, 120, 20))
faintSwatter = pg.Surface((400, 510))
faintSwatter.fill((220, 250, 120))
faintSwatter.set_alpha(128)
realswatter = pg.Surface((400, 510))
realswatter.fill((220, 250, 120))


def gameloop():
    fly = pg.Rect(100, 150, 70, 70)
    x_change = 0
    y_change = 0

    swatter = pg.Rect(90, 50, 400, 510)
    swatter_timer = 3
    swatterImg = faintSwatter # Current swatter image.

    dt = 0
    gameExit = False

    while not gameExit:
        for event in pg.event.get():
            if event.type == pg.QUIT:
                gameExit = True
            if event.type == pg.KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == pg.K_LEFT:
                    x_change = -5
                elif event.key == pg.K_RIGHT:
                    x_change = 5
                elif event.key == pg.K_UP:
                    y_change = -5
                elif event.key == pg.K_DOWN:
                    y_change = 5
            if event.type == pg.KEYUP:
                if event.key == pg.K_LEFT or event.key == pg.K_RIGHT:
                    x_change = 0
                elif event.key == pg.K_UP or event.key == pg.K_DOWN:
                    y_change = 0

        fly.x += x_change
        fly.y += y_change

        swatter_timer -= dt
        # If the timer is below 1.5s and above 0s, change the current
        # image and check for collisions with the swatter rect.
        if 0 < swatter_timer < 1.5:
            swatterImg = realswatter  # Change current image.
            if fly.colliderect(swatter):
                print('Collision!')
        # If timer is below 0s, reset timer and image and get a new pos.
        elif swatter_timer <= 0:
            swatterImg = faintSwatter  # Reset current image.
            swatter_timer = 3
            swatter.topleft = (random.randrange(displayrect.w-400),
                               random.randrange(displayrect.h-510))

        # Draw everything.
        gameDisplay.fill((30, 30, 30))
        gameDisplay.blit(flyImg, fly)
        gameDisplay.blit(swatterImg, swatter)

        pg.display.update()
        dt = clock.tick(60) / 1000

if __name__ == '__main__':
    gameloop()
    pg.quit()
    sys.exit()
```

Comment: Thanks so much skrx! The code works very well and I will implement your changes/suggestions into the game! I plan on additionally making a starting screen and removing the auto-quit function. It would be very impractical to have a game that constantly quits! Thanks again my friend!